# FAILED ERROR: Database connection error. php -f install.php magento

Tags: php, mysql, shell, magento

I can't install `magento` with command `php -f install.php`

but it can be installed from navigator

this is the command

```
php -f install.php -- --license_agreement_accepted "yes" --locale "fr_FR" --timezone "Europe/London" --default_currency "MA" --db_host 172.0.0.1  --db_name magento --db_user root db_pass password --url mag --uento.localdomain se_rewrites "yes" --use_secure "no" --secure_base_url "" --use_secure_admin "no" --admin_firstname "admin" --admin_lastname "user" --admin_email "email@test.ma" --admin_username "z.alimouch@medasys.ma" --admin_password "magento2014"
```

this is the message return

```
FAILED ERROR: Database connection error.
```

Comment: So I can see lots of typos in the command you called. It is possible there are typos in your call to the script too. I'm not too sure why you wouldn't have copied and pasted the output in your terminal (or whichever) window...
your host is `--db_host 172.0.0.1` but surely you mean `127.0.0.1` (of course you could actually have the ip address 172...
there is no "--" before db_pass which would invalidate that argument..
`--url mag --uento.localdomain` should probably be `--url magento.localdomain` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php -f install.php -- --license_agreement_accepted "yes" --locale "fr_FR" --timezone "Europe/London" --default_currency "MA" --db_host "localhost"  --db_name "mm" --db_user "root" --db_pass "root" --url "magento.localdomain" --use_rewrites "yes" --use_secure "no" --secure_base_url "" --use_secure_admin "no" --admin_firstname "admin" --admin_lastname "user" --admin_email "email@test.ma" --admin_username "z.alimouch@medasys.ma" --admin_password "magento2014"
```

You have to create database and virtual host beforehand. Installer will not do it for you.

Comment: yes i create database magento but what is virtual host

Comment: --url "**magento.localdomain**"